# Is using 204 http status code to do "ajax" forms considered "good practice"?

Tags: ajax, http

I want to do html forms that submit in the background. I currently use a external library ([jquery ajax form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)) in order to this.

I just learned about the 204 http status code which tells the agent not to redirect. In my tests when a form submit callback returns this code the web browser (chrome) stays on the same page. Would using this status code instead of a library to do ajax forms be considered a good practice or should I continue using a library for this? Do most browsers support it? Why do libraries even exist if there is a status code to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> **204 Status code** 
>   The server has fulfilled the request but does not need to return an
>   entity-body, and might want to return updated metainformation. The
>   response MAY include new or updated metainformation in the form of
>   entity-headers, which if present SHOULD be associated with the
>   requested variant.

Status code 204 can be used for ajax requests. Response with 204 status code is meant to say to the client that the request has been successfully accepted/executed but there is no entity body in the response. But there can be updates in meta information. i.e you can add updates to the headers.